# understanding formulas and multiple quantifiers

Tags: logic

I'm struggling to see the differences in exchanging quantifiers in the following example:

Define a formula 
$P(a,n,b): a = nb$ 
where $n$ is a variable in $\Bbb{N}$ and $a$ and $b$ are variables in $\Bbb{Z}$. Consider the following statements:

$(\exists n \in \Bbb{N})  (\forall a \in \Bbb{Z}) (\exists b \in \Bbb{Z}) P(a,n,b) $
$(\forall n \in \Bbb{N})  (\exists a \in \Bbb{Z}) (\forall b \in \Bbb{Z}) P(a,n,b)$ 
$(\exists n \in \Bbb{N})  (\exists b \in \Bbb{Z}) (\forall a \in \Bbb{Z}) P(a,n,b) $
$(\forall a \in \Bbb{Z}) (\exists n \in \Bbb{N}) (\exists b \in \Bbb{Z}) P(a,n,b)$

What do they mean, and which are true? How are they different and how should I read or interpret them?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's not quite true: $\exists n\in\mathbb{Z} P(a, n, b)$ means that $b$ divides $a$ without remainder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete the other answers, if your confuse comes from the succession of quantifier:

When you have a formula of the form $\forall a\exists b P(a,b) $ that means that for any $a$ you can find a $b$ that satisfy $P(a,b)$. In other words the $b$ you pick depend of $a$.

However when the formula is $\exists a\forall b P(a,b)$ you have to first pick $a$ and then check that $P(a,b)$ is true for every $b$. Thus, first you fix $a$ independently of $b$, and then you verify for each $b$.

Comment: Thanks! So you can think of it as "choosing" the variables from left to right? That makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @amathstudent Yes exactly (except that you only choose the $\exists$, and not the $\forall$ that rang over all the domain anyway). A variable that you "choose" may only depend on the variable that are on it's left.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple quantifiers of the same type in a row, you can combine them, correct?

Comment: @amathstudent Yes because if you "choose" two times in a row you can anticipate your second choice. Thus to take the same words as in my answer your first choice may depend of your second choice. More formally $\exists a\exists b P(a,b)$ is equivalent to $\exists b\exists a P(a,b)$ and we some times write it $\exists a,b P(a,b)$ (and idem for two $\forall$)

Answer (score 0):

Sign $\forall$ means "for every" and sign $\exists$ means "exists" or "there is".

Ill interpret first example.

"There is $n\in \mathbb N$ such that for every $a\in \mathbb Z$ there is $b\in \mathbb Z$ such that $P(a,b,n)$ is valid."

Statement is true because there is such $n$, (we can take $n=1$) that for every $a\in \mathbb Z$ there is $b\in Z$, (we can take $b=a$) such that $P(a,n,b)$ is valid: $a=1\cdot a\checkmark$

Comment: Okay, I understand that. So are all of the statements true?

Comment: No. You can show that second statement is false by finding its negation and showing that negation is true. Third statement is false, and fourth is true.